# PowerShell Move Duplicates to Dup Folder

Tags: powershell, loops, move

Below is what I currently have and it is working. However, If I have a duplicate is just spits out an error and doesnt move the file.. obviously. How can I implement to move said duplicate file(s) to a folder that already exists (I dont want it to create a folder)

```
$srcRoot = "\\networkdrive source"
$dstRoot = "\\networkdrive dst"

# Map to destination subdirectory based on first 2 chars of file name
$map = @{
    '02' = '02 Folder'
    '13' = '13 Folder'
    '30' = '30 Folder'
    '33' = '33 Folder'
    '58' = '58 Folder'
    '82' = '82 Folder'
    '86' = '86 Folder'
}

$fileList = Get-ChildItem -Path $srcRoot -File -Force -Recurse
foreach ($file in $fileList)
{
    $key = $file.BaseName.Substring(1,2)
    if ($key -in $map.Keys)
    {
        $fileName = $file.Name
        $dstDir = Join-Path -Path $dstRoot -ChildPath $map[$key]
        # Create destination directory if needed
        if (-not (Test-Path -Path $dstDir))
        {
            #mkdir -Path $dstDir
        
        }
        Write-Verbose "Moving $($file.FullName)"
        if (Test-Path -Path (Join-Path -Path $dstDir -ChildPath $fileName))
        {
            # Error message if file already exists at destination
            Write-Error -Message "File $fileName already exists at $dstDir"
        } else {
            # OK to move file
            Move-Item -Path $($file.FullName) -Destination $dstDir
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so ... how do you want to handle the "already there" files? you have not made that clear. [*grin*] ///// my pref would be to add a timestamp to the `.BaseName` of each file. that would mean you would have NO dupes [as long as you used a small enuf time unit].

Comment: @Lee_Dailey True, but in the end.. duplicate files would be more of an error from our user base. More or less i would just want the file that failed to move to an "Error" folder. There our users would be able to manually look at these select few files and see what went wrong with their naming process. I guess im looking for an addition where any file that doesnt match the mapping to be moved to a single folder where they had no place to go that can be sorted manually. If that makes sense.

Comment: To move to what folder if there are duplicates? What do you mean by moving to a folder that already exists? What folder?

Comment: @MediumRare - there is still a chance that files will be dupes in the error dir, but that is something you can deal with if needed. [*grin*] ///// for the dupes, use a test for that and move the file to the error dir. for the leftovers ... add a final step that moves the left over files to the error dir.